# How to get important keywords from a text in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I want to extract only relevant keywords from text. For example: from "I want to buy 10kgs of watermelon", i want keywords with tags- action:buy, quantity: 10 and target: watermelon.
The sentence can be more complex too, so how can i do this in python?

Comment: You better write how you have tried to solve your problem. Did you try it using Python? Peoples expect you to do a little more works before asking for help here.

Answer (score 1):

Your question addresses a big topic in natural language processing (the intersection of computer science and linguistics). There's a lot of material to get into, but I'll list a couple good resources.

- Youtube course on NLP: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Dt_yh1mf_U&list=PLQiyVNMpDLKnZYBTUOlSI9mi9wAErFtFm

For your situation, I would pay close attention to syntactic parsing (i.e. Syntactic Structure Constituency vs Dependency) and named entity recognition.

- Stanford NLP Toolkit: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/

Stanford CoreNLP is a cutting edge, plug-and-play toolkit for several NLP tasks. It's written in Java, but has a wrapper for use in Python.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[Entity Recognition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZavB.png)

(1)You can perform entity recognition in python using NLTK
(2)You will get Part of speech tagging for each word in the sentence
(3)Then write a python code to give tags to part of speech
for example

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk import pos_tag
sentence = word_tokenize("I always lie down to tell lie")
pos=pos_tag(sentence)

for value in pos:
    if value[1]=='VB':
        print("action")
```

(1)Pos_tag will return the list object with word and part of speech associated with it.
Go through the image attached for better understanding

(2)You can define different tags with pos(part of speech) like **NN for target**, **CD for Quantity(Cardinal Number)**

You need to add multiple different conditions in if-else statement to get the proper tags